# How to select particular row in table when click on particular row

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have text box, date pickers and an add button. when i click add button the data entered in text box and date pickers should be populate in a table this much i have done.

Assume that i have populated three rows at the end of each row save and delete anchors is there when i click on save the particular row should save to know the values of particular row am printing in alert its showing blank spaces

Html:

```
<br>
     class Name<br><input type ="text" id="className"></input><br><br>
     Subject<br><input type="text" id="subJect"></input><br><br>
     Max<br><input type="text"    id="max"></input><br><br>
     Min<br><input type ="text" id="min"></input><br><br>
    Sd<br><input type="text" id="sd"></input><br><br>
     Ed<br><input type="text"    id="ed"></input><br><br>
      <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button><br><br><br>

 <table id="mytable1" border="1" class="tbinput" style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>class Name</th>
    <th>Subject</th>     
    <th>Max</th>
    <th>Min</th>
    <th>Sd</th>     
    <th>Ed</th>
    <th colspan="2">Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                var count = 1;
                $('#btnAdd').click(
                                function() {




                                    var newClassName = $('#className').val();
                                    var newSubject = $('#subject').val();
                                    var newMaxMarks = $('#maxMarks1').val();
                                    var newMinMarks = $('#minMarks1').val();
                                    var newSD = $('#txt5').val();
                                    var newED = $('#txt6').val();                               



                                    if(newClassName !=''){                              

                                    count++;
                                    var txtClassName = "txtClassName"+ count;
                                    var txtSubject = "txtSubject" + count;
                                    var txtMaxMarks = "txtMaxMarks" + count;
                                    var txtMinMarks = "txtMinMarks" + count;
                                    var txtSD = "txtSD" + count;
                                    var txtED = "txtED" + count;
                                    var txClassName="txClassName";
                                    var newTr = '<tr><td>  <input type="text" id='+ txtClassName + ' name='+ txClassName + '  value='+ newClassName +'  ></td><td><input type="text" id='+txtSubject+' value='+newSubject+' ></td><td><input type="text" id='+ txtMaxMarks+' value='+newMaxMarks+' ></td><td><input type="text" id='+txtMinMarks+' value='+newMinMarks+'></td> <td><input type="text" id='+txtSD+' value='+newSD+'></td> <td><input type="text" id='+txtED+' value='+newED+'></td> <td class="omit"><a href="#" class="save">save</a></td><td ><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></td></tr>';
                                    $('#myTable').append(newTr);                            

                                        }

                                    $("#className").val("");                                        
                                    $('#subject').val("");
                                    $('#maxMarks1').val("");                                        
                                    $('#minMarks1').val("");
                                    $('#txt5').val("");
                                    $('#txt6').val("")

                                });


            });
```

**Save**

```
     $(document).on('click', '.save', function(e){
    var inputs = "";
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('omit')){
     inputs += $(this).text() + " , "; 
    }
  });
  alert(inputs);
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Selecting a row?  Removing a row?  Making an ajax call?  All 3?

Answer (score 0):

Use `on()` for dynamically appended elements.

Save details

```
<a href="#" class="save">Save</a>

$('body').on('click', '.save',function(){
   //Do your coding here          
});
```

Delete Details

```
<a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>

$('body').on('click', '.delete',function(){
   //Do your coding here      
   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //Remove clicked TR    
});
```

**Things to note**

- Don't forget to apply dynamic unique ID to all the elements or you can use  class selector.
- Apply the name attributes to all the inputs.
- Use `serialize()` or `.serializeArray()` to get values and then you can use `ajax` to save details.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var count = 1; 
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
var newClassName = $('#txt1').val();
var newSubject = $('#txt2').val();
var newMaxMarks = $('#txt3').val();
var newMinMarks = $('#txt4').val();
var newSD       = $('#txt5').val();
var newED       = $('#txt6').val();

    count++;
    var txtClassName = "txtClassName" + count;
    var txtSubject = "txtSubject" + count;
    var txtMaxMarks = "txtMaxMarks" + count;
    var txtMinMarks = "txtMinMarks" + count;
 var txtSD = "txtSD" + count;
 var txtED = "txtED" + count;


  var newTr = '<tr><td><input type="text" id='+txtClassName+ ' value="'+newClassName+'" name="'+txtClassName+'" /></td><td><input type="text" id='+txtSubject+' value="'+newSubject+'"   name="'+newSubject+'" /></td><td><input type="text" id='+ txtMaxMarks+' value="'+newMaxMarks+'"  name="'+newMaxMarks+'"  /></td><td><input type="text" id='+txtMinMarks+' value="'+newMinMarks+'" name="'+newMinMarks+'"></td> <td><input type="text" id='+txtSD+' value="'+newSD+'" name="'+newSD+'"></td> <td><input type="text" id='+txtED+' value="'+newED+'" name="'+newED+'"></td> <td><a href="#" class="save">Save</a></td><td ><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></td></tr>';
    $('#myTable').append(newTr);
    

});

  $('body').on('click', '.delete',function(){
    //Do your coding here      
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //Remove clicked TR    
  });
  
  
  
  $('body').on('click', '.save',function(e){
        e.preventDefault() // don’t let it submit
    //Do your coding here      
        console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('input').serialize());
   //Ajax clal
  });
  

});
```

```css
table tbody tr:hover {
 background-color: orange;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Class:<input type="text" id="txt1" />
Subject :<input type="text" id="txt2" />
Max Marks :<input type="text" id="txt3" />
Max Marks :<input type="text" id="txt4" />
Start Date :<input type="text" id="txt5" />
End Date :<input type="text" id="txt6" />


 <button type="button"  id="btnAdd" class="button-add">Click Me!</button>
<br><br><br><br>


  <table id="myTable">
    <th>class</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Max Marks</th>
    <th>Min Marks</th>
 <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th colspan="2">Action</th>
</table>
```

Comment: Delete is working properly.. How to get particular row to save particular row using ajax

Comment: Provide name attributes to all the inputs while appending and then use `serialize` or `serializeArray()` to get values and then use Ajax for the same.

Comment: using id's we can get right but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Why you're using `id`, you need to specify the names for all the inputs , and get it by `serialize`

Comment: See I've updated my answer with example to show what I am talking about. Do let me know if you've any questions?

Comment: txtClassName3=pp&pp=pp&pp=pp&pp=pp&pp=pp&pp=pp

Comment: its not coming in this way txtClassName=someclass&subject=somesubject

Comment: @srinivasgowda You need to provide the proper names as per your need, I just shown you a way to do it.

Comment: $('body').on('click', '#save', function(e){
         console.log("came here");
        var inputs = $(this).closest("tr").find('input');
        var inputValues = "";
        $(inputs).forEach(function(input){
         inputValues += $(input).val();
        });
        //console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('input').serialize());
   //Ajax clal
  });

Comment: Don't use ID man, see my answer and example that will allow you to achieve that.

Comment: What exactly issue you're getting? can you update your question and details about the issue now ?

Comment: when i  click save help me to get like this  var className=....   var subJect=...... so on

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.save', function(e){
 var inputs = "";
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('omit')){
    inputs += $(this).text() + " , "; 
    }
  });
  alert(inputs);
});

Comment: i have tried something to save please check it out why am getting empty

Comment: use `$(this).val()` not `.text()`

Comment: No even this one printing as space

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to the delete or save anchor tag and then set a click event on them as `$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){` and find their closest parent `tr` using `$(this).closest('tr')` and delete it using the `remove()` function

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
      console.log('here');
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();

})
```

Similary you can do the same for the save function where you can find the relevant tr and then operate on it

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ag2g5eds/4/)